# Unable upload image file using node.js/puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So far, I've tried two things.

```
const iconupload = await page.$x(xpath); //Triple-checked that this x path is correct
iconupload[0].uploadFile(picture); //Triple-checked that this picture path is correct
```

And

```
await page.evaluate((picturepath) => {
    document.querySelector('input[type=file]').value = picturepath
}, picturepath);
```

For the first method, I get a

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploadFile' of undefined
```

For the second method, I get a

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
```

Is there any way to upload an image to this input?

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please provide more detail like the DOM or HTML you're trying to access with xPath and the file input element you're trying to upload with.

Comment: @Trobol uploading an image to my google account page

Comment: @EdiImanto <input type="file" style="height: 0px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"> ... I can provide more HTML code if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Turns out, the image input in question was inside an iframe element. After doing some digging, I found that if an iframe element is contained inside of the page, normal puppeteer functions do not work. This is because, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression), typical puppeteer functions like page.$x, page.$, and page.waitFor are actually SHORTCUTS for page.mainFrame().$x, page.mainFrame().$, and page.mainFrame().waitFor(). Thus, these methods don't work on a secondary frame contained within the page

Here was what I did to overcome this. I first got the iframe's link from the src attribute. Then, I created a new page, and had this new page go to this link. Then, I could just scrape as normal. Here's a paraphrased snippet of my code:

```
let framelink = await page.evaluate(() => {
     return document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1].src;
}); 
const picturepage = await browser.newPage();
picturepage.goto(framelink)

//Now I can just scrape normally using methods like picturepage.$x
```